# Analytical form of this particular series summation, $\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_i^2 \exp(-ax_i^2)=?$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_i^2\exp(-ax_i^2)=?$
I am looking for an analytical expression for the above summation

Comment: Do we know anything about the $x_i$'s? If not, it is unlikely that there will be a simpler way to express that summation.

Comment: I we don't know anything more about the $x_i$, we are out of luck. If we do know something about the $x_i$, we are almost certainly out of luck.